# Is it allowed to use ∃y-elimination rule when you have: ∀x∃y φ?

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am given the following expression: ∀x∃y R(x, y) ⊢ ∃y∀x R(x, y) and I have attempted solving it as:

`∀x∃y R(x,y)      premise
  | ∀x R(x,y0)    assumption
  |  | x0
  |  | R(x0,y0)   ∀xe 2
  | ∀x R(x,y0)    ∀xi 4
  | ∃y∀x R(x,y)   ∃yi 5
∃y∀x R(x,y)       ∃ye 1, 2--5`

My concern is the first assumption, and therefore the use of the ∃y-elimination rule. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: No, you cannot remove $\exists$ before $\forall$ in $\forall x \ \exists y$. Quantifiers must be "unpacked" the outermost first.

Comment: For these questions, it is often useful to test them on easy formulae. For instance, let us define $R(x, y) \iff x = y$. The left premise is obvious (just take $x = y$), the right premise is trivially false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to apply the rules for the outermost operator first. Logically, you are saying that there is one $y_0$ satisfying $R(x,y_0)$ for all $x$ which is a wrong deduction.